# Is G♭M7 the same as G♭7?

Tags: chords

Are the chords G♭M7 and G♭7 both the chord of "G flat Major seventh"?

I'm looking at some sheet music.
Bar 1 has a G♭M7 and bar 2 has a G♭7?

I thought "M" means major and that if there's no "M" or "m"(minor) then the default is Major - so why even write "M" for the one and not the other?

I also see a chord that is BM7. Why not just B7?

Answer (score 0):

A major 7th chord is usually written Maj7, and that indicates a major triad with a major 7th added, e.g. G B D F#. But sometimes it’s written as M7.

A minor 7th chord is usually written m7, with a lowercase m, and that indicates a minor triad with a minor 7th, e.g. G Bb D F.

A dominant 7th chord is usually written as just 7, and that indicates a major triad with a minor 7th, e.g. G B D F.

Comment: Suggested edit: minor seventh chords are also sometimes written "-7".

Answer (score 0):

The essential difference is that "7" chords contain the interval of a minor seventh above the root; whereas, "M7" chords contain a major seventh above the root.

- "GbM7" is a "major seventh" chord, spelled `Gb Bb Db F`. (Gb to F is a major seventh.)
- "Gb7" is a "dominant seventh" chord, spelled `Gb Bb Db Fb` (Gb to Fb is a minor seventh.)

The two chords tend to operate differently. Major seventh chords (M7) tend to be "stable" chords -- meaning, they serve to represent a particular key (Gb major, for example). Dominant seventh chords are less stable and "want to move" to another chord: A Gb7 chord could be expected to move to a B chord or perhaps an F chord.

Comment: Gb7 is likely to move to Cb or Cbm, as indicated in another q/a from OP, who may have difficulty with finding Fb as well.